# error :requests.exceptions.ConnectionError

Tags: python, http, sharepoint, python-requests

i tried to connect share point with two ways:

```
#one way 
server_url = 'http://*****/'
site_url = server_url + '*****'
opener.open(server_url)
opener = basic_auth_opener(server_url,'****', '******')

#another way
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
reportReq = requests.get('%s:%d/' % ('http://*******', 80),     auth=HTTPBasicAuth('*****', '****'), verify=True)
```

here is the error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='***', port=80): (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

Comment: Did you forget a colon: `requests.get('%s%d/'` -> `requests.get('%s:%d/'`

Comment: i tried but the same error